# clang linker command fails saying that not found for architecture i386

Tags: macos, assembly, linker

Today I have update my system to Majove. And when I want to run my program again I encountered this problem.

The code I write is to transform a source code to assembly. The assembly generated successfully but when I tried to use nasm and clang to execute the .s file, the following error appeared.

```
alu-mac:01-adder-MRVERNEY Alu$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
alu-mac:01-adder-MRVERNEY Alu$ make tests/output/lets.run
nasm -f macho -o tests/output/lets.o tests/output/lets.s
clang  -g -m32 -o tests/output/lets.run c-bits/main.c tests/output/lets.o
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_printf", referenced from:
      _main in main-4f8e04.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [tests/output/lets.run] Error 1
rm tests/output/lets.o
alu-mac:01-adder-MRVERNEY Alu$ make tests/output/lets.run -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

I think this might be the clang fault and try to install another LLVM version, it did not work as well. And also I have tried to a different gun/make but it still did not work.

Hope you can help me. Thanks for you help in advance:)

Comment: [XCode 10 Note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes): The macOS 10.14 SDK no longer contains support for compiling 32-bit applications. If developers need to compile for i386, Xcode 9.4 or earlier is required. (39858111)

Comment: I have upgraded my Xcode to 9.3 but still do not work. I have not dealt with SDK things, should i upgrade SDK to earlier version either? I compile my program in command line